# Replace empty char with comma in every row of csv column in python

Tags: python, string, csv, strip

I have a csv of emails in one column named "email". They all contain an additional space at the end of the string.

```
email
email@email.com + " "
```

How do I strip the space?

I've tried several solutions such as:

```
f = r'C:path\emails.csv'
rw = open(f)
r = csv.reader(rw)
for lines in r:
   for l in lines:
       l.replace(' ', ',')
       print(type(l), lines)
```

prints:

```
<class 'str'> ['email@email.com ']
```

with the space.

I need the email addresses to be comma separated in the string and I can't even get them there by using a list wherein they would be inserted because of the quotes and spaces.

Comment: What's the format of the CSV file? That replace could cause you issues later.

Comment: You need `l = l.replace(' ', ',')`, but if you're replacing all spaces you don't need to do this in python.

Comment: first I have to add all the emails to an empty string excluding the '  ', then add a comma after each .com, then write each individual email to a csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strip` method to remove trailing space.

**Ex:**

```
f = r'C:path\emails.csv'
rw = open(f)
r = csv.reader(rw)
for lines in r:
   for l in lines:
       l = l.strip() #Removes trailing space.
       print(type(l), lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this replaced email to some value or append to new list.

```
f = r'C:path\emails.csv'
rw = open(f)
r = csv.reader(rw)
for lines in r:
   for l in lines:
       with_out_space = l.replace(' ', ',')
       print(type(with_out_space), with_out_space)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('emails.csv', 'r') as emails:
reader = csv.reader(emails)
l = list()
for line in reader:
    for i in line:
        vals = i.split()
        l.append(vals)
l.sort()
n = list
for email in l:
    s = ''
    s = s + email[0] + ','
    print(s)
    n.append(s)
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(s)
```

I should clarify that I need to write the emails with the commas to a csv. And this doesn't work. I can't append a string to the list n.

TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'

and printing the vals prints a list with an email address as a string in the list, not the address without a space at the end by itself